# Smoothing values (neighbors between 1-9)

Tags: python-3.x

**Instructions:** Compute and store R=1000 random values from 0-1 as x.    moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors) is pre-loaded into memory from  3a. Compute the moving window average for x for the range of    n_neighbors 1-9. Store x as well as each of these averages as    consecutive lists in a list called Y.

**My solution:**

```
R = 1000
n_neighbors = 9

x = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(R)]
Y = [moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors) for n_neighbors in range(1,n_neighbors)]
```

where moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors) is a function as follows:

```
def moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors=1):
    n = len(x)
    width = n_neighbors*2 + 1
    x = [x[0]]*n_neighbors + x + [x[-1]]*n_neighbors
    # To complete the function,
    # return a list of the mean of values from i to i+width for all values i from 0 to n-1.
    mean_values=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        mean_values.append((x[i-1] + x[i] + x[i+1])/width)
    return (mean_values)
```

This gives me an error, **Check your usage of Y again.** Even though I've tested for a few values, I did not get yet why there is a problem with this exercise. Did I just misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction tells you to compute moving averages for all neighbors ranging from 1 to 9. So the below code should work:

```
import random

random.seed(1) 

R = 1000
x = []
for i in range(R):
    num = random.uniform(0,1)
    x.append(num)

Y = []

Y.append(x)

for i in range(1,10):
    mov_avg = moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors=i)
    Y.append(mov_avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `moving_window_average(list, n_neighbors)` function is not going to work with a n_neighbors bigger than one, I mean, the interpreter won't say a thing, but you're not delivering correctness on what you have been asked.
I suggest you to use something like:

```
def moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors=1):
    n = len(x)
    width = n_neighbors*2 + 1
    x = [x[0]]*n_neighbors + x + [x[-1]]*n_neighbors

    mean_values = []
    for i in range(n):
        temp = x[i: i+width]
        sum_= 0
        for elm in temp:
            sum_+= elm
        mean_values.append(sum_ / width)

    return mean_values
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for +100XP

```
import random

random.seed(1) 
R=1000
Y = list()
x = [random.uniform(0, 1) for num in range(R)]
for n_neighbors in range(10):
    Y.append(moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your code could work, would be much more helpful, if you explain why original code from question do not work. At least, add some explanation to your code.